# Apache POI -- Font color is reverting back to default font color(black) on double clicking the cell in excel

Tags: java, excel, memory, garbage-collection, apache-poi

I am working on generating excel in xlsx format programmatically using Apache POI 3.9.

For a particular column, all the cell values should be in blue font. My sheet has more than 1500 rows and minimum 50 columns.

I have a method which returns the blueFont color style. Here's the code:

```
public CellStyle createBlueFont(){
    CellStyle fontStyle = workbook.createCellStyle(); // Creates new style
    Font blueFont = workbook.createFont(); // Creates new font
    blueFont.setColor(HSSFColor.BLUE.index);        
    fontStyle.setFont(blueFont);
    fontStyle.setWrapText(true);
    return fontStyle;
}
```

The above method is called each time the cell is created.

Excel is generated without any exception. But, when I double click on a cell which has a value filled with blue font, it reverts back automatically to black (default color).

I solved this issue by creating style and font globally.
I don't understand why my older approach is wrong.

**Note :** Am using SXSSF library for workbook and spreadsheet creation.
Could somebody please explain me where I was wrong in my previous code?

Thank you
Aswini J

Comment: Excel has a hard limit on the number of cell styles a file can have. They are workbook objects not cell objects, so don't create them for every cell!